# How can I invoke a form when an item from the navigation menu is clicked?

Tags: html, wordpress, forms, web, navigationbar

I am trying to develop a website where I want to have a 'Contact Us' tab in the navigation menu on all pages however, I don't want it to take the user to a new page where he can do his submission. I want to invoke a new dialog/window when this is clicked that has the form. After the submission, the dialog/window is closed with a message of successful submission and the user remains on the same page as where he was when he clicked 'Contact Us'. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Details:
I am using WordPress for my website and the plugin - Quforms for the form.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know details about Quforms. But if you can display form made by Quforms in template files like footer or header, make a form, hide that form and then write a jquery script to show that form on nav menu item click. Also you can use popup library to display this form in a popup.